# clear cookies and try login

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I have a login functionality(all using jQuery plugin) using a pop up and once the login is complete, cookies are set with user information and the user is logged in. The login happens using an iframe that accesses a protected page and authenticating with the valid user credentials. When I clear the cookies, the iframe is not longer able to access the protected page and I'm seeing permission denied error in JavaScript. Is there a generic solution to clear out the iframe contents after detecting cookies has been cleared by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a "cookies have been cleared" even that you could listen for in Javascript. If the iFrame is hidden and the error is of no consequence, you could simply wrap the code that throws the permission denied error in a try/catch block and display a user-friendly "You have been logged out" message.